# How to generate a parameter array

Tags: dml-lang

I am now developing a management unit that controls several IPs through corresponding control-fsm. These IPs are grouped in several group, and each group are controlled by one control-fsm. Thus I have a control_fsm_template and a ip_template, and in each control_fsm there is a parameter ip_list to record all IPs controlled by this FSM:

```
template control_fsm_template {
    param ip_list : sequence (ip_template);
    param ip_list default undefined;
    method gm1() {
        foreach ip in ip_list {
            if (ip.p1) ip.m1();
        }
    }
}
template ip_template {
    param p1;
    param p2;
    connect c1;
    port c2;
    method m1() {}

    method m2() {}
} 


group ip_1 is (ip_template);
group ip_2 is (ip_template);
group control_fsm1 is (control_fsm_template) {
    param ip_list = [ip_1, ip_2];
}

group ip_3 is (ip_template);
group ip_4 is (ip_template);
group control_fsm2 is (control_fsm_template) {
    param ip_list = [ip_3, ip_4];
}
```

DMLC reports error:
error: not a value: [ip_1, ip_2]

And then I changed the code to:

```
template ip_group1_template is (ip_template);
template ip_group2_template is (ip_template);
group ip_1 is (ip_group1_tempalte);
group ip_2 is (ip_group1_template);
group control_fsm1 is (control_fsm_template) {
    param ip_list = each ip_group1_template in (dev);
}
group ip_3 is (ip_group2_tempalte);
group ip_4 is (ip_group2_template);
group control_fsm2 is (control_fsm_template) {
    param ip_list = each ip_group2_template in (dev);
}
```

Then DMLC reports error:
error: wrong type in assignment
got: list of trait ip_group1_template
expect: list of trait ip_template

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on how you intend to use the inner_group parameter, perhaps with a concrete code snippet that dmlc reports errors on?

Comment: Depending on how the param is used, this may or may not be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75073681/cannot-use-variable-index-in-a-constant-list

Comment: Can you please edit the question and fold that clarification into it? Normally I would suggest an edit but can't do this now because stackoverflow is overwhelmed.

Comment: Hi Erik, I updated the post, could you please help to have a look again? Many thanks!

Comment: Good question! In particular, the second part of the question is interesting, and the question reduces to "why you cannot cast a `sequence(X)` to `sequence(Y)`, given that `template X is Y`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your first attempt is that `[]` lists are not true values; they are purely compile-time entities that only support three operations: `#foreach`, `#select`, and direct indexing with a constant; therefore you cannot assign them to a typed parameter. The only way to construct values of type `sequence(X)` is currently `each .. in ..` expressions, as you correctly realized in your second attempt. The problem there is instead that DML doesn't offer a way to convert a `sequence(X)` into a `sequence(Y)`, even if `template Y is X`. This would be a valid feature request.

The simplest solution is to use nested groups, so you can say collect all instances within a subhierarchy instead of `dev`:

```
template ip_group1_template is (ip_template);
template ip_group2_template is (ip_template);
group fsm1 {
    group ip_1 is (ip_group1_tempalte);
    group ip_2 is (ip_group1_template);
}
group control_fsm1 is (control_fsm_template) {
    param ip_list = each ip_template in (fsm1);
}
group fsm2 {
    group ip_3 is (ip_group2_tempalte);
    group ip_4 is (ip_group2_template);
}
group control_fsm2 is (control_fsm_template) {
    param ip_list = each ip_template in (fsm2);
}
```